# Not to get all data in Autodesk_data_extract after executing DATA CONNECTOR

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I have tried all extract data after executing the data connector in BIM360 for the Executive overview.[Please find the image where I have used a data connector in BIM60 to download data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p3FC.png) Then I have downloaded a compressed(zipped) Folder. Then I received all Microsoft Excel comma-separated values files. But most of those files are empty such as for example- `checklists`,`cost`, `forms`, `submittals`, `sheets`, `rfis`, etc...[Please find the image of autodesk_data_extract Microsoft excel comma-separated values file where the above-mentioned file are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb6Sr.png)

Comment: since you have also  sent this question to forge.help, let us discuss there. To clarify, this is rather a product question, because you used the UI function directly. The best place is https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-support/bd-p/183, but I can try to help for your convenience this time.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang thank you for the response! Okay, No problem let's discuss it there. Forums Autodesk would be nice place to discuss then,

Comment: my pleasure. Have you posted on forum? I do not seem to find it. just want to watch until it is resolved. Or if you prefer to discuss with me in the other private thread (forge.help email, ticket number  #11601)

Comment: I didn't post on the forum because of some reason. we shall discuss it on the private thread as it has belong to particular product services.

Comment: There is already one request mentioned. Please refer to message number 6 - https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-support/powerbi-com-autodesk-data-connector/m-p/10379338#M16979